# How to print a pdf file in color using Adobe reader in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, printing, colors

In my C# winform application, I print silently a pdf file by using Adobe Reader DC. The pdf file should be printed in color, but the printing preferences of printer's settings is on Black and White. How can I change this property and set it on color programmatically. 
Here is my code to print silently:

```
public void StartPrinting(string fullFilePathForPrintProcess, string printerName)
        {
            string printApplicationPath = FindAdobeAcrobatPath();
            const string flagNoSplashScreen = "/s";
            const string flagOpenMinimized = "/h";

            var flagPrintFileToPrinter = string.Format("/t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", fullFilePathForPrintProcess, printerName);

            var args = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", flagNoSplashScreen, flagOpenMinimized, flagPrintFileToPrinter);

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                            {
                                FileName = printApplicationPath,
                                Arguments = args,
                                CreateNoWindow = true,
                                ErrorDialog = false,
                                UseShellExecute = false,
                                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                            };

            var process = Process.Start(startInfo);

            // Close Acrobat regardless of version
            if (process != null)
            {
                process.WaitForInputIdle();
                process.CloseMainWindow();
                process.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "...the printer property of Adobe Reader is always set on Black and White"?

Comment: @Formula12 Sorry for bad explanation, I have colored pdf document and I use Adobe Reader to print it. But in printer settings, printing preferences, is set on Black and white. So the output is in Black and white. After more searching in net, I found out I need to change printing preferences through my C# code, and still I do not know how. I do appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
private void MyButtonPrint_OnClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    // Set the printer name and ensure it is valid. If not, provide a message to the user.
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\mynetworkprinter";

    if (printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid) {

        // If the printer supports printing in color, then override the printer's default behavior.
        if (printDoc.PrinterSettings.SupportsColor) {

            // Set the page default's to print in color.
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;
        }

        // Provide a friendly name, set the page number, and print the document.
        printDoc.DocumentName = "My Presentation";
        currentPageNumber = 1;
        printDoc.Print();
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Printer is not valid");
    }
}
```

Full code can be found at

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.supportscolor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Drawing_Printing_PrinterSettings_SupportsColor)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess printDocument class does not support pdf files. Am I right?

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if that answers your question.

Comment: I tested the printDocument class to see whether it prints pdf file. Unfortunately, it doesn't. Many developers use a pdf library or Adobe Reader to perform it.